# Error re-creating user profile service application

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

We have 2013 on-prem farm. I have deleted the User profile service application  with the associated data. Now I am trying to recreate the service application but I am getting errors.
When I tried to create the service application with the same database the error message says the database exits although I checked the database is not there

When I tried to re-create the service application with the default database names I get the following error

> Sorry, something went wrong
>
> The object 'sap_get_para' is dependent on database collation. The
>   database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends
>   on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and then
>   retry the operation.
>
> The object 'sap_read_text' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object
>   depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and
>   then retry the operation.
>
> The object 'sap_fn_jobrepair_vars' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound
>   object depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database
>   collation and then retry the operation.
>
> The object 'sap_tsql_createcntr' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound
>   object depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database
>   collation and then retry the operation.
>
> The object 'sap_tf_dboptions' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object
>   depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and
>   then retry the operation.
>
> The object 'sap_tr2_filterview' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound
>   object depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database
>   collation and then retry the operation.
>
> The object 'sap_tr2_traces' is dependent on database collation. The
>   database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends
>   on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and then
>   retry the operation.
>
> The object 'sap_p_counter' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object
>   depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and
>   then retry the operation.
>
> CREATE DATABASE failed. The default collation of database 'Profile DB' cannot be set to 'Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS'.

Thank you  for your help in advance

Comment: Have you also deleted the Profile DB, Sync DB and Social DB? Take also a look at the technet description https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg985419.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I deleted those three DB ; when I  recreating the service it was saying the database exists. Unfortunately this happened in QA. No backup being taken. Hence I can not restore the service from the backup.